# Submitting edit on Super User fails

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editing

When I try to edit [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/128304/), I get a page not found error.

The error:
[Page not Found http://ep2up.com/uploads/1270635831.png](http://ep2up.com/uploads/1270635831.png)

**Edit:**

Now it works again. But this wasn't the only error. I've tried to answer my own question, and it gave another error message.

Comment: FWIW, you need freehand circles for that screenshot to add any value.

Comment: For information, it works when I edit it.

Comment: I got another error (the "it's our fault" problem) when trying to add an answer to it.

Comment: @Ikke: what operating system and web browser, etc. are you using? And what versions of those?

Comment: Windows 7 x64 Chrome 5.0.356.2

Answer (score 1):

It is an intermittent bug, on the order of 5%. It has been like that for 1-2 days.

The work-around is to save the edited content somewhere, go back to the original page, press edit, paste in the saved content and try again.

Comment: really?  weird, i haven't seen it at all.  probably haven't made quite as many edits as you have, but i've made a few.

Comment: Well, i've tried it multiple times, and every time it gave that message.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL you are taken to which produces the 404?

I can edit questions I have posted without any issue...

Comment: It was something like /posts/128304/edit-submit/48593aae-9d1e-46bb-a7c4-2253cf15df5a.

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce this.